# Why is the function created is not working.?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I was working on the library project and in it when a person presses the add button the  Javascript and have to print in console "hey great u have submitted the form "  and its not working. Please help with it.

html

```
<form id="libraryform">
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="bookname" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bookname" placeholder="book name pls">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="author" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">author</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" placeholder="author pls ">
    </div>
  </div>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <legend class="col-form-label col-sm-2 pt-0">genre of book</legend>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="fiction" value="fiction" checked>
          <label class="form-check-label" for="fiction">fiction</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="programming" value="programming">
          <label class="form-check-label " for="programming">computer programming</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check ">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="type" id="cooking" value="cooking">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="cooking">cooking</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" id="librarysubmit" class="btn btn-primary">add book</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and Javascript code here is:

```
let librarysubmit = document.getElementById("librarysubmit");
librarysubmit.addEventListener('submit', libraryformsubmit);
function libraryformsubmit() {
    console.log("hey great u have submitted the form ");
    e.preventdefault() 
    e.preventdefault() 
}
```

Comment: Check your console. You have a few errors in it.

Comment: What is `e`? `e.preventdefault()`, hint you forgot to declare it. Also make sure to set up your console to retain data on navigation so you can see the errors and console logs.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Especially important: the section headed "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem".

Answer (score 1):

You are using the event submit on a button. You need to attach the event on the form.

Like

```
document.getElementById("libraryform")
```

And your js function is not valid, you forgot the params event

```
function libraryformsubmit(e) {
  console.log("hey great u have submitted the form ");
  e.preventDefault() 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two minor things to change

1.
From

```
let librarysubmit = document.getElementById("librarysubmit");
```

to

```
let librarysubmit = document.getElementById('libraryform');
```

Because - submit event is triggered on the form.

2. change `e.preventdefault()` to `e.preventDefault();` Captialize D in default.

Demo Link: https://codepen.io/punith/pen/GRJpOrz?editors=1011